# How to change theme on Dialog Cast Companion Library android

Tags: android, dialog, chromecast, castcompanionlibrary

I'm using Cast Companion Library android.

I want to change some color like text color, play, pause button to Dark.
Right now is in Light color.
Any suggestion to do this?

[This is the screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbrWq.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding some code on activity, from this link:

http://explod.io/setting-the-theme-of-mediaroutechooserdialog/

```
    MediaRouteDialogFactory mMediaRouteDialogFactory = new VideoMediaRouteDialogFactory() {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment onCreateChooserDialogFragment() {
        return new MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment() {
            @Override
            public MediaRouteChooserDialog onCreateChooserDialog(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                return new MediaRouteChooserDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog);
            }
        };
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    mMediaRouteMenuItem = mCastManager.addMediaRouterButton(menu, R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MenuItem routeItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(routeItem);
    mediaRouteButton.setDialogFactory(mMediaRouteDialogFactory);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can u please share full source of it ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to or managed by CCL; in that dialog, theme is managed by [MediaRouteThemeHelper](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/mediarouter/src/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouterThemeHelper.java). You can override `Theme.MediaRouter.Light.DarkControlPanel` and `Theme.MediaRouter.LightControlPanel` styles in your own application and that will adjust the theme of your dialog.